# Eclipse not recognizing the new jars when migrating from Play Framework 2.4.2 to 2.5.0

Tags: eclipse, playframework, java-8, playframework-2.5

I've been trying to migrate from Play 2.4 to 2.5 by following the [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25), and I've upgraded my sbt version to 0.13.11 and ensured that I'm using Scala 2.11. I believe I've been able to successfully migrate to 2.5 because I've changed my routes to fit the new default `InjectedRoutesGenerator`, but I can't seem to use the new `play.libs.streams.Accumulator` in a custom `BodyParser` I want to make.

Any ideas as to why I might not be able to reference Accumulator? If it helps, even when I clean, build, and refresh my project in Eclipse, the referenced jars stay as `<jar_name>_2.11-2.4.2.jar`.

Comment: How did you "import" your project to Eclipse? Using the `sbt eclipse` command provided by sbteclipse-plugin?

Comment: As @marcospereira said, run "sbt eclipse" and refresh the project on eclipse.